PhpStorm's Database tool is not able to connect to MySQL after upgrade to version 9.0.1 using Homebrew
PhpStorm's Database tool is not able to connect to MySQL after upgrading to version 9.0.1 using Homebrew. I am able to use database using phpMyAdmin and can connect it using PHP applications. I am currently in skip-grant-tables mode.
Has somebody faced this issue and resolved it already?
I have tried using different drivers of MySQL connector in PhpStorm, still no success

So .. what kind of error message it shows etc? Just stating "it does not work" will not take you far...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It says connection refused. That's it.

I figured it out, when MySql server is running in skip grants table mode, phpstorm MySQL connector is not able to connect to it.
When I disabled skip grants table mode phpstorm database tool was able to connect to MySql server with configured username and password.
When I was using skip grants table mode I was trying to just give username to the database tool and connect but the connection was not working. I don't know but may be it is a security feature or may be i would be missing some configuration.

I had the same problem using mysql 9 official docker image. I solved it by not trying to connect to the database as root. Try to connect using the credentials defined on DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD image env variables
